# Custom editing functionality for SharePoint web parts

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-branding

I am trying to develop web parts with custom functionality for editing for normal users. In the chrome bar there would be the same sort of controls as you see in the top right of your browser (except with a triangle instead of a line).

- Triangle is to minimise/restore (as in OOB, but with different display)
  Square is to maximize a new module type window, probably with an iFrame displayed in a module type view window with jQuery with an additional field to add the url to where it should go
- Cross is to delete web part
  The functionality is required across a few different types of web parts including calendar, CBQ, Data View, CBQWP, and would ideally be a part of a custom chrome that would be added to them. I don't do back end code so I'm finding it hard to get my head around how someone would put together the functionality. Unless it's simple it won't be me writing this functionality. I have Enterprise 2010 for development, but the people using the control would only have foundation.

I'm basically after opinions about how this would be done. I think it should be a custom control written into the chrome, if that's possible. Does that seem feasible or is there a better way of doing it?

I would really appreciate any advise, even if it's just that it would be better to skin the existing chrome and leave the functionality as is. There's leeway with the functionality so at this stage it's deciding on how best to do it if it's possible or not too bother going down that route.

Thanks very much in advance!!

Comment: what do you mean with "normal users"?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear at all. Students that log on to the portal who will access to edit the view of their page and the way that certain web parts are displayed.

For these controls on the web parts the user will just be changing the way that the web part is displayed or delete it.

Comment: I guess you're trying to create a igoogle way of sharepoint, right? I guess your students will not have any permissions to create or edit a webpart as a user like in ldap or sth. So I guess all you need to do is to create a webpart that takes a parameter like the "controlledWebPartName" and that webpart can have minimize, delete buttons and it can do these operations while the code to be elevated as admin user, otherwise no user can edit or delete a webpart without permissions. So all you've have to do is, create a webpart like this, load it above all the webparts to be customized and set wpId

Comment: or if I understood you correctly as it is really a igoogle approach, you can do this by javascript and get the result you've wanted with just a diplay:hidden style setting operation

Comment: I've just realised how much information my question actually lacked. The customisations are for the users individual, personal MySite page. I am using publshing functionality for some parts of the page, namely with the web parts that will be fixed on the page that the users can not change. So for the functionality it would be very similar to igoogle.

The average intranet user (without admin rights), would be able to customise 4 web parts in the bottom row of the page and move them within these 4 columns. By customize I mean, minimise, maximise, delete, just the ones mentioned above.

Comment: The javascript way sounds like a good possibility, the only thing is that the users MySite should remember any settings the next time a user logs onto the system. Would there be a way of storing the changes if I were to go down that road?

Comment: yes sure, javascript can set a cookie that can only store the [webpartname, int] value that can let you decide to show that or not like 0 for deleted, 1 for minimized, 2 maximized. so you should first check if the user has a cookie, if yes then arrange the webpart using this data, if not then show them all the way; and when clicked one of your maximize or sth button, you will just update the cookie value. I think jscript is the best way to do it (although I hate that language)

Comment: you can checkout a web site using sharepoint webparts and css&javascript friendship to achieve what you've wanted; that is an airport's website here in turkey link: http://www.ataturkairport.com/

Comment: That would be perfect if each user were just going to use one computer, but then if the user logged out and somebody else logged in it would remember the last users settings. The way I am trying to do it is for the settings to be remembered so that the next time they logged in from any computer it would have their settings saved.  It's not like igoogle in that way. It's a SharePoint MySite customisation for their personal home page. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't know whether it would be possible, but using JavaScript originally for the hide/show/minimise customisations to edit the view client side with those settings getting posted server side and being saved when ever the user left the page would be ideal. Something like that.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can use client api of sharepoint to get the currentUser's username to set in the cookie? the other way is not a good to go way if you think about using server side controls because they will bring you the overhead to keep a list to record the personalizations and every operation will need a postback and that means a big overhead over a single list I think; but if you like it that way, all you need to do is to create a "smartpart" like control that will contain the info about the webpart associated to control its properties using admin rights, as we talked about before.